# WPF if statement based on radio button checked or not

Tags: wpf, checked, jradiobutton

I'm having difficulty with something which seems like it should be very simple.  I'm coming from Windows Forms and starting up with WPF.  I think I have a simple syntax issue but I can't seem to find a specific example for this radio button issue.

I have a radio button on my GUI for a query to run either via a map selection or a list. When load is clicked, it should perform one operation if map is selected, a different operation for list.  Code looks similar to this:

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (rdBtnList.Checked == true)
  {
    //do this
  }

  // if rdBtnList not checked (ie if rdBtnMap is checked)
  // do this
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking unless you're asking what the statement is to run the second "do this" if the button is not clicked.. in which case it's else :D

Comment: More of a "different" //do this.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
if (rdBtnList.Checked == true)
```

to

```
if (rdBtnList.IsChecked == true)
```

**Note:**

`I'm coming from Windows Forms and starting up with WPF`

- You must forget everything you ever learned in winforms, and embrace MVVM. You should create a ViewModel and bind your `rdBtnList.IsChecked` property to some boolean value in the ViewModel, then perform your logic in there. The views' code behind is not the right place for application logic.

Comment: Its difficult to forget everything about Windows Forms.  I'm having to utilize Forms for some things also (not necessarily by my choice).

Comment: @nallware once you realize how simple everything is in MVVM, you'll never want to go `back` to winforms.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll agree by default, but when you're told "do it this way" you "do it this way". *shrugs*

Answer (score 1):

The property in WPF is called `IsChecked` hence you just need to update the `if` statement

```
if (rdBtnList.IsChecked == true) { 
  ...
}
```

The `IsChecked` property is `bool?` (nullable value) in WPF so you may choose to be more explicit here by doing the following

```
if (rdBtnList.IsChecked.HasValue && rdBtnList.IsChecked.Value) { 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a return statement? As is, the posted code will always execute the if not checked path:

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (rdBtnList.IsChecked == true)
  {
    //do this
    return; // return, or the if not checked path below will always win.
  }

  // if rdBtnList not checked (ie if rdBtnMap is checked)
  // do this
}
```

In WPF, you'll need to use the IsChecked property. See the [RadioButton Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.aspx) for more details.