# Powershell GUI not registering Radio Button as clicked

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$var_executeButton.Add_Click( {
    if ($var_radioButton.Checked) {
        ..do stuff
    }
})
```

however, the code inside the if block never run, even if radio button is checked.

Code outside of the if works just fine.

Can you please tell me why?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15620034/45375, the property name is `.IsChecked`, not `.Checked`.

Comment: You are really not showing enough of your code to see if there are other circumstances in play. Are you trying to do an action when a button is radio button is clicked, or are you present radio buttons, and taking an action, after something else is done and validating, if a radio button is checked before some other action is taken?

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, IsChecked worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. There ways to take action on form elements at the time they are acted on or checked later. As an example here is a simple WinForm, that discovers all radio button controls on a form and takes the same action when any one of them is clicked.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$objForm.Text          = "Test"
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 200)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$RadioButton1          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
$RadioButton1.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
$RadioButton1.Checked  = $false
$RadioButton1.text     = "Button1"
$objForm.controls.Add($RadioButton1)

$RadioButton2          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 50)
$RadioButton2.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
$RadioButton2.Checked  = $false
$RadioButton2.text     = "Button2"
$objForm.controls.Add($RadioButton2)

$OKButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 120)
$OKButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150, 30)
$OKButton.Text         = "OK"
$OKButton.Enabled      = $false
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$objForm.AcceptButton  = $OKButton

$objForm.TopMost = $True

$objForm.Controls | 
Where-Object { $PSItem -is [System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton] } | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $PSItem.Add_Click( 
    { 
        If (-Not $OKButton.Enabled)
        {$OKButton.Enabled = $True}
    }) 
}

$Form = $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

To see if a radio button is checked, you can use either `.Checked`,

```
# Example - check radio button state on OK click.
function Test-RadioButtonCheck  
{
    Param 
    (
        $title,
        $a1,
        $a2,
        $a3
    )

    $form                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Size           = '300,250'
    $form.Text           = $title
    $form.StartPosition  = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

    $label1              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label1.Location     = '15,15'
    $label1.Width        = 100
    $label1.Text         = 'Enter some text'
    $form.Controls.Add($label1)

    $textBox1            =  New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox1.Location   = '115,15'
    $textBox1.width      = 150
    $textBox1.Name       = 'input'
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox1)

    $radio1              =  New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    $radio1.Location     = '25,40'
    $radio1.Text         = 'Check me if you want the save'
    $radio1.Width        = 200
    $form.Controls.Add($radio1)

    $button              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Location     = '70,70'
    $button.Text         = 'Ok'
    $button.DialogResult = 'Ok'
    $form.Controls.Add($button)

    if($form.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok')
    {
        if($textBox1.Text)
        {
            if($radio1.Checked){$form}
            else{[void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('You didn''t check the radio button','Error')}
    }
    else{[void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('You didn''t enter any text','Error')}
    }
}

if($frm = Test-RadioButtonCheck  'Test form')
{Write-Host "You entered $($frm.Controls['input'].Text)" -ForegroundColor Green}
```

.IsChecked as per mklement0's link, or looping to find them:

```
Where {$PSItem -is [system.windows.controls.radiobutton] -and $PSItem.IsChecked} | 
Select Name
```

... or using `[System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton]::CheckedEvent` as per this WPF example:

```
[xml]$xaml  =  @"
<Window 
    xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name = "Window" Title = "Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight" ShowInTaskbar  =  "True" Background = "lightgray"> 
    <StackPanel x:Name = 'StackPanel'> 
        <RadioButton x:Name = "Item1" Content = 'Item1'/>
        <RadioButton x:Name = "Item2" Content = 'Item2'/>
        <RadioButton x:Name = "Item3" Content = 'Item3'/>  
        <Separator/>
        <TextBox x:Name = 'textbox'/>      
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
"@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | 
ForEach {Set-Variable -Name ($PSItem.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($PSItem.Name) -Scope Script}

#Bubble up event handler
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$Script:CheckedEventHandler  =  
{$TextBox.Text  =  $PSItem.source.name}
$StackPanel.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton]::
CheckedEvent, $CheckedEventHandler)

$Window.Showdialog() | Out-Null
```

If you want dig at the explanations of the WPF and radio button options, then see this blog post regarding the samples shown:
https://learn-powershell.net/2014/08/10/powershell-and-wpf-radio-button

***If the aforementioned is not what you are doing, then as per my comment, you are not showing what the use case really is.***